# Linker error, Xcode 5 and Armadillo: "library not found for -larmadillo.4.0.2"

Tags: xcode, linker, armadillo

I'm trying to install and compile a small example program using the Armadillo framework, unfortunately I'm getting linker errors. Here are my steps so far:

- Installed Armadillo
- Edited config.hpp to remove the constant definition of
  `ARMA_USE_WRAPPER`
- Added the accelerate framework to the Xcode project
- Added `/usr/include/` to header search paths
- Added `/usr/lib/` to library search paths
- Added `libarmadillo.dylib` to the "Link Binary with Libraries"
  section
- modified include statements to `#include "/usr/include/armadillo"`

Specifically, the linker error I get in Xcode 5 is as follows:

```
> ld: library not found for -larmadillo.4.0.2 clang: error: linker
> command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Does anybody have any clues as to what I'm missing/doing wrong? I've tried the solutions posted in similar questions with no success, thanks in advance!

**edit**: interestingly, compiling and running the example programs in Terminal functions correctly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure why, but removing the link to `libarmadillo.dylib` in the "Link Binary with Libraries" section has solved the problem and the program now compiles!